# MPMediaPickerController with MPMediaTypeMusic "for you" or "browse" is empty

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmediapickercontroller, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am using the `MPMediaPickerController` to playback my own files (locally or purchased in the cloud). This is the code i use

```
musicPickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
musicPickerView.alpha = 0.0f;
musicPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
musicPicker.showsCloudItems            = true;
musicPicker.delegate                   = self;
musicPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false;
musicPicker.prompt                     = NSLocalizedString(@"Select a song", @"Select a song");
musicPicker.view.frame                 = musicPickerView.bounds;
[self addChildViewController:musicPicker];
[musicPickerView addSubview:musicPicker.view];
[self.view addSubview:musicPickerView];
[musicPicker didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self fadeInMusicPicker:true];
```

Everything is working fine except the tabs "for you" and "browse". I have an active apple music subscription (verified with `SKCloudServiceCapability` -> `musicCatalogPlayback`).

But when opening the `MPMediaPickerController` i see an infinite spinner.

**Any idea what i might be doing wrong?**

This is the infinite spinner view inside my apps `MPMediaPickerController`
[image]

Comment: Does the behavior change if you set musicPicker.showsCloudItems = true to musicPicker.showsCloudItems = false. I am wondering if something is getting hung up connecting to the store?

Comment: nope.. unfortunately the same. Is it important to use the MusicKit api to sign in and all of this manual rest api communication stuff?

Comment: I am not sure Martin. I haven't run into the same issue as you in my use of MPMediaPickerController. Do you happen to have an example that reproduces the issue that I could take a look at?

Comment: Hey Martin? Did you ever figure this one out? I'm also seeing the spinner on MPMediaPickerController in the "For you" and "Browse" sections. Looking at the "Library" section works fine and I can see all downloaded music. In the search bar, it does actually populate search suggestions from Apple Music, but when you tap one of them, it does the same spinner thing. iOS 13.3.1 here, Xcode 11.4, iOS SDK 13.4